# iOS: Name of image used in XIB

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xib, nscoder

Is there any way to find out in code name of image was used in XIB for eg background for a button?

Let say I have xib with button which has property Background (for State Config: Default) set as "button.png", button has an IBOutlet eg myButton. When my view is created from xib I can easily access image by: [myButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] but it's of course UIImage, but I need to find name of image ("button.png") was used in xib.

I've tried to subclass UIButton and find something with NSCoder inside initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder but without results

Part of xib where button's background is defined is

```
<object class="NSCustomResource" key="IBUINormalBackgroundImage">
    <string key="NSClassName">NSImage</string>
    <string key="NSResourceName">button.png</string>
</object>
```

was trying something like:

```
NSObject * obj = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"IBUINormalBackgroundImage"];
```

but doesn't work (how to get use of NSCoder when initializing from nib?)

Also was trying to override

```
-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state{
    [super setBackgroundImage:image forState:state];
}
```

But is never called, however in awakeFromNib everyting is already initialized and loaded.

Can anyone explain / help with this, please?

Comment: Once you've converted a png or whatever into a UIImage you lose the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, once an UIImage, no reference is kept from the original file name.

But if you need it from an UIButton, you can circumvent the issue by using the **accessibility identifier** of its imageView. This method should be available on any class subclassing UIView.

```
NSString *filename = [button.imageView accessibilityIdentifier] ;
```